# query returning wrong result for like'%'

Tags: laravel-5

like % not working . the query returning result for full string match not the substring match.

```
 Booking::whereHas('agent', function ($query) use ($agent_name) {
            $query->where('first_name', 'like', "'%".$agent_name."%'");
    })->select('id','agent_id','file_number','title','first_name','last_name','ref_number','pax_adult','pax_child')->with(array('agent'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','first_name','last_name');
    }))->get();
```

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes around the like string: $query->where('first_name', 'like', "%".$agent_name."%");

Comment: May be you  can use: `$query->where('first_name', 'like', $agent_name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query to:

```
$query->where('first_name', 'like', "%".$agent_name."%");
```

You had a extra `'` at the start and end of the `LIKE`.